# How does the optimizer in Oracle Database use I/O statistics?

Tags: oracle, optimization, storage

I would like to help Oracle's query optimizer make better-informed decisions. I have been unable to find much information on how the optimizer determines the cost of I/O operations, other than unsourced remarks that it uses the time that it takes to retrieve a single data block. Here are some things that I would like to know:

1. Is it possible to view the current I/O benchmarks used by the optimizer?
2. Is it possible to trigger an update of those benchmarks?
3. Does the optimizer account for the *current* I/O cost of an operation? For example, if there is heavy concurrent load on the storage device causing a reduction in performance, does it consider that the relative cost of I/O will temporarily be higher?
4. Does the optimizer consider latency/random-access performance versus throughput/sequential performance?
5. If you have data files on multiple storage devices with different performance characteristics, does the optimizer have and apply device-specific costs?

Comment: (5) seems to imply that you have a bad physical design. All the disks in your disk group [ASM]/RAID set should have the same performance characteristics.

Comment: For (5), I didn't say that the devices were in the same RAID set. I am talking more of employing tablespaces with different performance characteristics for different intended usage patterns. For example, one could use cheap, slow storage for infrequently-accessed readonly data, low-latency storage for objects subjected to a lot of random access, etc.

Answer (score 2):

1. You can see currently used statistics in `SYS.AUX_STATS$`.
2. `DBMS_STATS.GATHER_SYSTEM_STATS` collects system statistics. Running it with `gathering_mode='NOWORKLOAD'` will capture IO related stats of the server. You usually also run it under workload ("START/STOP", "INTERVAL").
3. (4,5)  Collecting system statistics during typical load should take care of potential problems you mentioned. 
   In addition , (4) will be affected by optimizer mode (`ALL_ROWS` vs `FIRST_ROWS`)

Also, with procedures in `dbms_stats` packages it's possible to collect stats multiple times, export (`EXPORT_SYSTEM_STATS` ), import (`EXPORT_SYSTEM_STATS`), or delete it (`DELETE_SYSTEM_STATS`).

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any real answers.  I mainly have pointers for where you can go to look for more information.

## Viewing I/O Statistics (1)

You might enjoy this URL:

http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/12c/r1/poster/OUTPUT_poster/poster.html#

It appears that Oracle keeps "round trip" information within V$FILESTAT.

## Updating I/O Statistics (2)

Oracle ORION was the first thing that came to my mind.  After a quick search, it appears that there is a DBMS Package to update I/O statistics.

https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/measuring-storage-performance-for-oracle-systems

## Question 3 and 4

I only have my own thoughts and reasoning.

## SAS vs SATA (5)

The concept of "different characteristics" is not foreign to the Oracle Database (at least, not within the documentation).  12c's `ILM` clause allows you to automatically move data from a tablespace on ASM diskgroup `[+SAS]` to a tablespace on ASM diskgroup `[+SATA]`.

However, I would not mix files with different characteristics within the same tablespace.

## Inner/Outer Sections of a Disk Platter

ASM seems to have the ability to distinguish these.  I would look through the documentation.

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/OSTMG/GUID-857680CA-35B0-4C88-9DF4-55537C8F1B7C.htm#OSTMG13790